# Server side app to retrieve email notifications from long-running processes, summarize the contents, and show a summary all in one webpage

Tags: web-apps, email, notification

I administer and monitor several processes that run in different servers - each process, whether they finish successfully, with errors, or don't even complete at all, sends an email notification with some important information regarding the status of the process.  I'm looking forward for a tool that allows me to review those emails, and gather the relevant information from each email, and then display it in a web page so anyone from my team can review it.  I know I can build a tool like this by myself, but I wonder if there's an open source tool like this out there.

It would be great if the tool is able to:

- allow the setup of multiple email/subject/body rules, pretty much like what you do in MS Outlook
- the web page showing the results should enforce some type of authentication
- provide some kind of calendar, so you can schedule *emails to be received*, and to fire alerts and display in the web page the email notifications that you didn't receive
- a web administration-interface to setup the accounts is preferred, although a CLI interface is OK too
- running on Linux is preferred, but Windows is OK too